# Reducing the distance between two boxplots

Tags: matplotlib

I'm drawing the bloxplot shown below using python and matplotlib. **Is there any way I can reduce the distance between the two boxplots on the X axis?**

[image]

This is the code that I'm using to get the figure above:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'
rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'

fig = plt.figure()
xlabels = ["CG", "EG"]
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.boxplot([values_cg, values_eg])
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(xlabels))+1)
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, rotation=45, ha='right')
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
ylabels = yticks = np.linspace(0, 20, 5)
ax.set_yticks(yticks)
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels)

ax.tick_params(axis='x', pad=10)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', pad=10)

plt.savefig(os.path.join(output_dir, "output.pdf"))
```

And this is an example closer to what I'd like to get visually (although I wouldn't mind if the boxplots were even a bit closer to each other):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the aspect ratio using

```
ax.set_aspect(1.5) # or some other float
```

The larger then number, the narrower (and taller) the plot should be:

> a circle will be stretched such that the height is `num` times the width. `aspect=1` is the same as `aspect=’equal’`.

http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect

Comment: I chose this as the answer because setting the aspect is really what I was missing, but in the end the solution also implied changing the boxes' width, as per @tcaswell's answer.

Comment: This actually completly messes up the y ticks and y labels as it just kind of zooms in. It actually does not decrease the distance between the boxplots like it has been asked.

Comment: To clarify, the *apparent* distance between the boxes can be changed by adjusting the scale (with `aspect` or `figsize`) or limits of the *x*-axis (with `xlim` or "zooming").  The *true* distance between boxes (much like points on any scatter plot) cannot be changed from their fixed *x*-values (`1, 2, ...` in this case).  This will also make the boxes narrower, so as Filipe suggests it is wise to change their width as well.  I'm not sure how either would affect your *y*-axis ticks and labels, @b00n12.  I suggest adjusting your parameters for aspect ratio and boxplot width.

Comment: Yeah, I already solved it, thank you anyway. Just wanted to point out that this does not realy answer the question. Your comment is actually completely right though!

Answer (score 12):

You can either change the aspect ratio of plot or use the `widths` kwarg [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot) as such:

```
ax.boxplot([values_cg, values_eg], widths=1)
```

to make the boxes wider.

Answer (score 1):

`positions :` array-like, optional

Sets the positions of the boxes. The ticks and limits are automatically set to match the positions. Defaults to range(1, N+1) where N is the number of boxes to be drawn.

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html

This should do the job!

Comment: Please cite the relevant content from the link. That makes your answer easier to read and once the link breaks, the relevant content stays on your answer.

Comment: Hi Joooeey.. Please advise on the best way to do this.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

As @Stevie mentioned, you can use the `positions` kwarg [(doc)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html) to manually set the x-coordinates of the boxes:

```
ax.boxplot([values_cg, values_eg], positions=[1, 1.3])
```