# Matplotlib boxplot spacing on x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I'm a beginner with python and matplotlib.  I have code to make boxplots.  The code works fine on small datasets, where there are not too many boxplots to draw.  When I scale up to more plots the spacing on the x axis becomes a problem and the boxes, and more importantly the x axis labels, are too close together.  I would sorely like to fix this and I'm sure there's a simple solution, I'm just too much of a noob.

Here's my code

```
    %matplotlib inline    
    plt.boxplot(data_sgc)
    plt.ylabel("Alignment Gap Score")
    plt.xlabel("Locus")
    plt.xticks(range(1,len(alignments.keys())+1), [i[1] for i in medians_sgc], rotation=90)
    remove_border()
```

Infuriatingly I can't show you the image I get because I need 10 rep or something daft like that.  Anyway, I expect I need to do something like set fig=plt.... etc. then do something downstream of that.

If you're kind enough to reply, please bear in mind that I'm a total noob, and that any explanatory information you can give me will be very much appreciated!

Here is a link to the data.  The order of is data_sgc, then medians_sgc, then alignments https://paste.ee/p/ay8zQ .   All of those were just printed - dat_sgc is not complete as you will see, but I hope this gives you context to understand the problem.

All I need is the code which will allow me to increase the spacing between the plots on the x axis.  Here is a link to the current output that I'm getting https://maxjohnlunt12.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/download-2.png although this screenshot was taken before I added in the argument to rotate the xlabels

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302718/reducing-the-distance-between-two-boxplots/16302837#16302837 <- probably related

Comment: Please include the data in `data_sgc` and `alignment` to create a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better help you.

Comment: @MackM - The data is many thousands of characters - is that really necessary?

Comment: @Max John  Reduce the problem until it can be easily fit here, if possible.  Either you'll solve the problem in the process (usually the case for me ;-) ) or you'll create an example that will let us reproduce your problem.  See at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: OK, I've edited the post to include the information you asked for, also a link to an image of the output I'm getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've got it sorted.  Increased the increment values in the range functions and reduced the xticks font size.

```
plt.boxplot(data_sgc, positions = range(4,(len(alignments.keys())*4), 4))
plt.ylabel("Alignment Gap Score")
plt.xlabel("Locus")
plt.xticks(range(4,((len(alignments.keys())+1)*4),4), [i[1] for i in medians_sgc], rotation=90, fontsize = 4)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', pad=4) 
plt.tight_layout()
remove_border()
```