# Adjust width of box in boxplot in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I would like to reduce the width of the boxes in the boxplot below. Here's my code, but it is not working:

```
bp = plt.boxplot(boxes, widths = 0.6, patch_artist = True)
```

[image]

Comment: The second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302718/reducing-the-distance-between-two-boxplots) might help you out.

Comment: hmm, i already have `widths = 0.6` in my code, but it is not working

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) there is a widths option:

> widths : array-like, default = 0.5
>
> Either a scalar or a vector and sets the width of each box. The default is 0.5, or 0.15*(distance between extreme positions) if that is smaller.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(937)
data = np.random.lognormal(size=(37, 4), mean=1.5, sigma=1.75)
labels = list('ABCD')
fs = 10  # fontsize

plt.boxplot(data, labels=labels, showfliers=False, widths=(1, 0.5, 1.2, 0.1))

plt.show()
```

[image: Result]

Comment: i already have 'widths = 0.6' in my code, but it is not working

Comment: you are right, but then what are you looking for? You are resizing ALL the boxes at 0.6 and it is working. If you want to have different sizes per box that try with the array-type

Comment: Is there an inbuilt variable for "distance between extreme positions"?

Answer (score 3):

Try working via the `axes` and see if it works:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.boxplot(boxes, widths = 0.6, patch_artist = True)
```